# Создание БД в Django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

Изучаю Django по немного устаревшему источнику. Раньше в Django база данных создавалась следующим образом:

```
python manage.py syncdb
```

Сейчас команда `syncdb` заменилась на `migrate`:

```
python manage.py migrate
```

Так вот. Раньше надо было указывать пользователя, мыло и пароль для владельца БД, а с командой `migrate` такого не трубется. Но почему ? Где все это указывается ?

Comment: Думаю раньше создавали суперпользователя для своей системы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`manage.py migrate` отвечает за изменение структуры БД (и как побочный эффект изменение данных при необходимости), но никаких новых данных с нуля не загружает. При этом по-хорошему вам следует сперва создать миграции командой `manage.py makemigrations` и уже потом применить их командой migrate.

Зато потом, в будущем, когда вам понадобится добавить, изменить или удалить какую-то модель, вам не нужно будет вручную редактировать БД, вызывая всякие `ALTER TABLE`, а достаточно будет вызвать снова `manage.py makemigrations` (джанга найдёт изменения и запишет их в файлы с миграциями) и потом просто применить созданные миграции командой `manage.py migrate`.

Подробнее о миграциях и как их писать самостоятельно (иногда это бывает нужно) можно найти [в любом современном учебнике](http://djbook.ru/rel1.9/topics/migrations.html).

Суперпользователь же как раньше создавался, так и сейчас создаётся командой `manage.py createsuperuser`, и теперь это делать надо самостоятельно, да.

Comment: А если не создавать суперпользователя, то что ? Ведь без него работает.

Comment: @faoxis а его и не обязательно создавать. Но обычно в джанге пользуют встроенную админку, а чтоб туда залогиниться надо какого-нибудь пользователя создать

Answer (score 1):

Команда `migrate` использует информацию из файла `settings.py`, а именно значение [`DATABASES`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#databases). Пример:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'mydatabase',
        'USER': 'mydatabaseuser',
        'PASSWORD': 'mypassword',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}
```

Comment: Но я использую SQLite, у меня нет такой подробной информации.

Comment: Насколько я помню, Django автоматически формирует `settings.py` при первоначальной настройке проекта. В качестве БД там используется SQLite. Попробуйте запустить команду [startproject](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/intro/tutorial01/#creating-a-project)